# Restrict users from creating administrators?

Tags: users

I want to give some users the ability to add and edit other users, but I don't want them to be able to add administrators (or for them to be able to give themselves or other users the "administrator" role).

This seems like something that would be commonly required, but I don't see any way to do it OOB, or any existing module.

Have I missed something or does this need doing as a custom module? If so, do you have any pointers on where to start? (Not with making custom modules, I'm familiar with that, but if you have anything to share about doing this in particular). Thanks!

EDIT: I can see how to stop users from assigning *any* role to other users, but I want them to be able to assign other roles, just not administrator.

Comment: Role delegation does that; Role assign does the same but doesn't have a stable release; there are probably more, like you say it's a common requirement

Comment: Thanks @Clive. It appears that role delegation has been discontinue (no support for Drupal 9) but replaced by https://www.drupal.org/project/delegate_permissions. Will check that out!

Comment: I use [Role Assign](https://www.drupal.org/project/roleassign) and despite it being a beta release, it has worked flawlessly for me for over a year.